# Ajax in ajax-changed DIV content

Tags: php, ajax, html

I'm using form for searching in db. The searching is going as the user is typing and you can see the results in a DIV (Formatted in a table).

The DIV content is changing as the user is typing (I use AJAX to change the content). When the user finds something he likes in the table, he's able to give it a "Thumb up". But, even i have this in my included .js:

```
$(".PlusAddImgs").click(function(){
 alert(' ');
});
```

And the PlusAddImgs is also class of IMG's, user can click on, it's not working.

I tried to make another image with same class in the DIV, and it work's until i start typing/searching/changing content.

So I thought maybe I need to include needed .js files also in the .php page I'm using to show me the tables, the one, witch ajax is workin with, why searching and geting data from the db.

Tried that, not working..

Can you please help me to ahieve my goal? I just need to use ajax in a changing content DIV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.live` handler:

```
$(".PlusAddImgs").live("click", function(){ alert("Hi!"); });
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally got that working, thanks to .live()! Thank you very much!!